# Connecting to Android Emulator using .NET C#

Tags: android, .net, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, networkstream

I am trying to connect to the Android Emulator using a `TcpClient`. The Emulator is Android 4.2.2 running on localhost:5554 which I start from AVD Manager. I am able to connect and to send 'power status discharging' command but after the second command is sent, the program hangs waiting for response. The commands works when I connect using Putty raw connection.

Here is the full code:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace AndroidBatteryChangeEmulator
{
    class Program
    {
        private static readonly TcpClient connection = new TcpClient();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Connect("localhost", 5554);
                NetworkStream stream = connection.GetStream();

                ReadDataToConsole(stream);
                SendCommand(stream, "power status discharging");

                string command = string.Format("power capacity {0}", 50);
                SendCommand(stream, command);

                stream.Close();
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The following error has occured: {0}", ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private static void ReadDataToConsole(NetworkStream stream)
        {
            var responseBytes = new byte[connection.ReceiveBufferSize];
            stream.Read(responseBytes, 0, connection.ReceiveBufferSize);

            string responseText = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseBytes).Trim(new[] { ' ', '\0', '\n', '\r' });
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(responseText))
                Console.WriteLine("Response: '{0}'.", responseText);
        }

        private static void SendCommand(NetworkStream stream, string command)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sending command '{0}'.", command);
            byte[] commandBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command + "\r");
            Buffer.BlockCopy(command.ToCharArray(), 0, commandBytes, 0, commandBytes.Length);

            stream.Write(commandBytes, 0, commandBytes.Length);

            ReadDataToConsole(stream);
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the output of the program:

```
Response: 'Android Console: type 'help' for a list of commands'.
Sending command 'power status discharging'.
Response: 'OK'.
Sending command 'power capacity 50'.
```

I am not sure what causes the problem.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is wondering, I fixed the issue by wrapping the `NetworkStream` with `StreamReader` in the `ReadDataToConsole()` function and `StreamWriter` in the `SendCommand()` function. 
Make sure that `AutoFlush` is `true` in `StreamWriter`!

Everything works now!

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind posting your working code? Here is the code I use (for future visitors):

```
using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient(host, port))
{
    using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
            {
                writer.AutoFlush = true;
                foreach (string command in commandList)
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(command);
                    string response = reader.ReadLine();
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Martin